# How can I populate a recycler card view in Android from an API response

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a unique response from an http GET request that I want to use to populate an android recycler view (using cardView).

Here is my response:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/tKvRclTeFduIQC9knqZs2CVfs7A\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
"regionCode": "EG",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 12,
"resultsPerPage": 1
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
"etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/faNNEg16szqlc3xWy6X39iKKx7g\"",
"id": {
"kind": "youtube#video",
"videoId": "bP2P0oqoX4U"
},
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2014-01-10T18:18:55.000Z",
"channelId": "UCbvwLzU45wgAHOqXRQoC11A",
"title": "تعرف على برنارد لويس صاحب مشروع تقسيم العالم العربي والإسلامي",
"description": "مقطع من خطبة: (الجمعة 9 من ربيع الأول 1435هـ الموافق 10-1-2014م), والتي هي بعنوان: (ماذا لو تخلى الشعب عن الجيش؟) الراب...",
"thumbnails": {
"default": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bP2P0oqoX4U/default.jpg",
"width": 120,
"height": 90
},
"medium": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bP2P0oqoX4U/mqdefault.jpg",
"width": 320,
"height": 180
},
"high": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bP2P0oqoX4U/hqdefault.jpg",
"width": 480,
"height": 360
}
},
"channelTitle": "موقع الشيخ محمد سعيد رسلان",
"liveBroadcastContent": "none"
}
}
]
}
```

I am kind of stumped where to start. I was thinking make a POJO from the JSON response.

Can someone direct to what is best software design practice on this with some example code?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://androidkt.com/rest-api-pagination-paging-library/

Comment: You will retrieve data with library like volley or retrofit and display it into recycleView by depend on pojo, i'm here for help if you facing something.

Comment: @Ibrahim thanks for the offer. Do you have a code example I could see?

Comment: @ironmantis7x take a look here http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-Add-items-Dynamically-in-RecyclerView/9560/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a collection of POJO using this response. And then pass that collection object to the `Recyclerview` adapter.

You can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) to generate POJO class.